# Flask Python: Unable to get parameters using request.args

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to request some parameters from a external web app. I create an API with flask and query data from MySQL. I **able to query the data** if I gave a **fix input** but **not when using request.args**. I try both `request.args['name']` and `request.args.get('name')` but return the output of Exception path.

Below is my current code. I comment out the fix input I used.

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

@app.route('/KLSE/search', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEsearch():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='vinus.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='vinus',passwd='Vindex2016',db='vinus$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    #name ='P'
    #macd = 'H'
    #volumeMin = '_'
    #volumeMax = '_'
    #stoch ='H1'
    #bollinger ='H'
    #rsi ='H1'
    #atr ='LV'
    #trade = 'HOLD'
    #limit = 3
    #offSet = 1
    name = request.args.get('name')
    volumeMin = request.args['volumeMin']
    volumeMax = request.args['volumeMax']
    macd = request.args['macd']
    stoch = request.args['stoch']
    bollinger = request.args['bollinger']
    rsi = request.args['rsi']
    atr = request.args['atr']
    trade = request.args['trade']
    limit = request.args['limit']
    offSet = request.args['offSet']

    query0 = "SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s' AND"
    #query1 = "(Vindex BETWEEN (IF(%s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s))) AND "
    query2 = "(Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF (%s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s))) AND "
    query3 = "MACD LIKE %s AND "
    query4 = "STOCH LIKE %s AND "
    query5 = "BOLLINGER LIKE %s AND "
    query6 = "RSI LIKE %s AND "
    query7 = "ATR LIKE %s AND "
    query8 = "TRADE LIKE %s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s" 
    query = query0+query2+query3+query4+query5+query6+query7+query8
    input = name+"%",volumeMin,volumeMin,volumeMax,volumeMax,macd,stoch,bollinger,rsi,atr,trade,limit,offSet
    try:
        curs.execute(query,(input))
        g = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': g})
```

The output with fix value as below. I think it shows the query to MySQL is correct.
http://vinus.pythonanywhere.com/KLSE/search1

For the user input value, which use the args,
[http://vinus.pythonanywhere.com/KLSE/search?atr=%&bollinger=%&macd=%&name=M&rsi=%&stoch=%&volumeMax=*&volumeMin=*&trade=HOLD&limit=5&offSet=1](http://vinus.pythonanywhere.com/KLSE/search?atr=%&bollinger=%&macd=%&name=M&rsi=%&stoch=%&volumeMax=_&volumeMin=_&trade=HOLD&limit=5&offSet=1)

What is the right way, get the parameters? volumeMin,volumeMax,limit and offSet are in float and integers.

Comment: `request.args.get('value', default=0, type=int)` as request.args is ImmutableMultiDict see [docs on get method here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.TypeConversionDict.get)

Comment: @PJSantoro, `request.args.get('name', default=0, type=str)`,`request.args.get('valueMin', default=0, type=float)` and `request.args.get('limit', default=0, type=int)`, is it correct?

Comment: yes, looks good! except maybe `request.args.get('name', default='', type=str)`

Comment: @PJSantoro, unfortunately, still return to the exception path. Any idea?

Comment: `WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'` is not correct as placeholders must not be quoted.

Comment: @mata, yes, after eliminate the single quote of %s, it works, but only for the name, whihc is the first arguments in query0. Others are still going to exception path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize your data first.

```
def serialize():
        return {
            "id" : g.id,
            "volumeMin" : g.name,
            "volumeMax" : g.address,
            "macd" : g.city,
            "stoch" : g.state,
            "zipCode" : g.zipCode,
            "bollinger" : g.bollinger,
        } 

@app.route("/KLSE/search/.json")
def stock_json():
    query = your.db.query()
    return jsonify(Stock=[i.serialize for i in query])
```